# Non-examples of mixed Tate motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, motives, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

I was trying to find examples of schemes (preferably smooth) over $\mathbb{C}$ which have motives that aren't mixed Tate. I wasn't able to come up with anything or find an argument that's been written down. Does anyone have an example or a reference for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Elliptic curve? Smooth genus g curve, g>0?

Comment: What's the reason for this?

Comment: Just look at the Hodge structure. Or look at them in the Grothendieck group of motives (equivalently look at the Hodge E-polynomial).

Comment: rvk is right. To say that the motive of some variety is mixed Tate is a *very strong* condition. So if you pick a variety "at random",  it probably won't satisfy this. Concretely, in higher dimensions, you can take smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $n+1$ or more. (Look at the Hodge numbers.)